# itorch creates a python console, not a torch console

Tags: ipython, torch

When I call `itorch` I don't get a torch console but an ipython console:

```
~$ itorch
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

IPython profile: torch
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-4469.json --profile torch

In [1]: require 'nn'
  File "<ipython-input-1-d76f3f5020d1>", line 1
    require 'nn'
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [2]: import os

In [3]:
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem (in my session IPython is v3.0.0) - have you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTorch supports iPython v2.3 or above. Please see the required dependencies.
 You seem to have iPython v 0.1.2, maybe that's a reason you see this behavior.